# How to fix exception Unable to load DLL 'gdiplus.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, docker, microservices, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing a service fabric mesh application in **.Net Core 2.1**, in which Can't use **System.Drawing.Common** in **microsoft/dotnet:runtime** (windows container)

### Below is my docker file code

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY MS_Upload/MS_Upload.csproj MS_Upload/

RUN dotnet restore MS_Upload/MS_Upload.csproj

COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/MS_Upload

RUN dotnet build MS_Upload.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish MS_Upload.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MS_Upload.dll"]
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Unable to load DLL 'gdiplus.dll': The specified module could not be found.
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCreateBitmapFromStream(IStream stream, IntPtr& bitmap)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream, Boolean useIcm)
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
   at MS_Upload.UserImageMaster.UploadAllChunkImageLibrary(Int32 iPeppyPrintID, Int32 iSourceID, String sAlbumID, Int32 iPickUpOrderID, String sFileName, Int32 iTotalChunk)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try using linux container instead as libgdiplus modules aren't installed by default on windows containers, most likely it will work without issues
- install system.Drawings dependencies using the following commands ([reference](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/618)):

  RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
      libc6-dev \
      libgdiplus \
      libx11-dev \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

you can use [chocolatey](https://superuser.com/questions/947220/how-to-install-packages-apt-get-install-in-windows) to install those dependencies on windows container if using windows image is necessary

Comment: I believe service mesh is *only* Windows.

Comment: i believe .net core apps can be containerized using either windows or linux containers but if your application has a requirement for windows containers to be used , you can install chocolatey as a package manager in the windows container and install those packages "libc6-dev , libgdiplus , libx11-dev"

Comment: Yes. .NET Core is cross-platform, but this is specifically about Azure Service Mesh, which I think is Windows only.

Comment: "Service Fabric Mesh can run Windows or Linux Docker containers" 
reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-tutorial-template-deploy-app

Comment: you can also refer to all templates deployment steps on linux and windows here for more information :
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-mesh/tree/master/templates

Comment: Unable to find gdiplus package in choco

Comment: as per this reference (https://repology.org/project/libgdiplus/versions) gdiplus doesn't exist in the default packages repository of chocolatey, so i believe you should build the package from source , the following article might help
(https://recordnotfound.com/libgdiplus-mono-129398)

Comment: @ahmedmaher Even if you build libgdiplus on Windows, System.Drawing.Common will not use it as it is hard-coded to use gdiplus.dll (the out-of-the-box Windows GDI+ implementation) instead of libgdiplus (the open source project). microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime is built off the windows/servercore container, and that container does not contain gdiplus.dll. Long story short, if you're using .NET Core in containers, System.Drawing.Common will only work on Linux.